# String termination in C- difference between storing and matching

Tags: c, string

This may sound a bit stupid but this is how I am getting it and I have googled it but no relevant solution was found.

```
I always thought that in C, strings was terminated by '\0'
```

is a single character. (hence we used single quotes)

Also, we are able to do something like,

```
while ( a[i]!='\0' )
do blah blah


which suggests that '\0'
```

is a single character and ideally should be stored in a single position.

But when I declare an array like this:

```
char a[3];
```

and when I try to put some value say "hi" in it.

Then

```
printing a[0] gives "h"
printing a[1] gives empty space  
printing a[2] gives 0
```

which is suggestive that \ was stored at position 1 and '0' at position 2. and the whole thing '\0' was not stored together despite us using it as a single character.

Why is it so? Can anyone shed some clarity on the same?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
int i=0;
char a[2];
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin); // Here I input "Hi".



while(a[i]!='\0')
    {
    printf("%c",a[i]);
    fflush(stdin);
    i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain what you mean when you say you "try to put some value" in the array. You're probably not doing it right, since '\0' is, in fact, a single character.

Comment: How are you putting the value "hi" into your array?

Comment: This just gives me "h". and when I individually print the array values, I get as described in the question.

Comment: @ChuckBlumreich now that I see your code, your array has room for two characters when it should be 3 (one for `h`, one for `i`, and one for `\0`), and in an array of size 3, the largest index is 2 because indices start at 0.

Comment: "when I declare an array like this: `char a[3];`", but your actual code contains `char a[2];`.

Comment: @Sylar please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8792970/726361), it explains the behaviour you're seeing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fgets` takes the size of the buffer as the second argument and reads that **minus one** characters, then makes the last character a `\0`. Because your array is sized 2 (which is too small for the string `hi`, by the way), `fgets` reads one character and makes the last character a `\0`, so you have an array that holds `h\0`.

To get it working, make your array sized 3; one for the `h`, one for the `i`, and one for the `\0`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    int i = 0;
    char a[3];
    fgets(a, sizeof(a), stdin); // Here I input "Hi".

    while(a[i] != '\0') {
        printf("%c",a[i]);
        fflush(stdin);
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh shit! Indeed. I was confusing the array size with index number. Apologies. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 2):

Strings are not terminated by the characters `\` and `0`, rather they are terminated by a NULL value (character 0), which can be represented through the escape sequence `\0` - similar to the way a carriage return can be represented by `\n`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. I just marked the representation that way because I wanted to highlight that they are not coming together when I print them. I am aware of the the escape sequence, carriage return, etc etc,

Comment: Yea sorry, I read it again.  You're doing something incorrectly when you're populating your array.

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[2];
fgets(a,sizeof(a),stdin); // Here I input "Hi".
```

The second argument of `fgets` is intended to receive the total length of the buffer, as you did; but a buffer 2 `char` big is enough just for 1 "useful" character and the null terminator, so `fgets` just stores the `H` and immediately writes the `'\0'` (`fgets` guarantees string termination, so it will always prefer to terminate the string instead of putting in another "real character" but not terminating the string).

After the `fgets`, your buffer will look like this in memory:

```
+---+---+
| H |\0 |
+---+---+
```

In facts, your program will actually write out just H. If you want to see the "actual numbers" stored in each char, you can do:

```
printf("%d %d", a[0], a[1]);
```

and you'll get `72 0` (where 72 is the `H` and 0 the `'\0'`).

([see example](http://www.ideone.com/z2ukC))

Comment: But it should ideally store 2 values and then write, '\0'. Shouldn't it? It has position 0, position 1 and position 2 to store at. So why just write 'h' and write out? Why not store 'i' also?

Comment: @Sylar: no, it has only position 0 and 1. When you write `char a[2];` you are asking for an array of *two* elements, i.e. index 0 and 1. In facts, `sizeof(a)` is evaluated to 2.

Comment: There's no space to write the `'\0'` too. You'll need x array elements for x characters plus one entry for the termination. So an array with 3 elements (`char text[3]`) will essentially be able to take a string with 2 characters only (unless you work without termination, but then you won't be able to use the give string functions).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: Yes, sorry! I just noticed I was confusing index numbers and array size. I had two different things write on paper and the code I was writing. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You're definitely missing some code here. How did you 'put' "hi" into the variable? I think you might have assigned the pointer instead of the whole string (which is essentially an array).

You can't copy strings by simply assigning them. Doing so at initialization (like `char test[] = "hello!";`) is a special exception.

```
char text1[] = "test"; // works (string is copied at runtime)
char text2[5]; // so far empty / content not defined
text2 = "test"; // won't work (depending on  your compiler settings it's possible there's no error, but you won't copy/assign the string)

strcpy(text2, "test"); // works, but might be unsafe (buffer overrun); requires string.h

text2[0] = 't';
text2[1] = 'e';
text2[2] = 's';
text2[3] = 't';
text2[4] = '\0'; // works too, but not recommended for longer stuff (1-2 chars is most likely okay, depending on the usage)
```

---

As mentioned in some other posts, your issue is your array being able to take a string of length 1 only (as I mentioned below, for a string to grab x characters, you need x+1 array elements (to store the terminating `'\0'`).

The string `"Hi!\0"` (note the explicit termination; just to show you) in memory will look like this: `0x00 0x48 0x69 0x21 0x00 0x00` The `\` is only in your written code to tell the compiler a special character will follow. The `\` won't appear in the final program code. Read a tutorial on string literals and escaping characters if you'd like to learn more about this.

Comment: Tried to proof why I wouldn't recommend doing it that way - fixed. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The '\0' is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

To copy "hi" to `char a[3]` all you need to do is call the `strcpy()` library function as follows.

```
strcpy(a,"hi");
```

And, `strcpy()` could look like this!

```
// array version
char * strcpy1(char to[], char from[])
{
        int i=0;
        while(from[i]) {
                to[i] = from[i];
                i++;
        }       
        to[i] = '\0';
        return to;
}

// pointer version
char * strcpy2(char *to, char *from)
{
        char *t = to;
        while (*to++ = *from++);
        return t;
}
```

Hope this helps!